# Liferay under IE8, YUI Error: Invalid Argument

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, liferay, windows-xp, yui

Im testing a Liferay 6.2 Portal on IE8 with Win XP and getting this error:

Webpage error details

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 18772
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://a3f36f75.ngrok.io/html/js/everything.jsp?browserId=ie&themeId=eacat_WAR_eacattheme&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&languageId=en_US&b=6210&t=1420466752000

Apparently is an error related to this function on the YUI module:

```
    /**
 * Sets a style property for a given element.
 * @method setStyle
 * @param {HTMLElement} An HTMLElement to apply the style to.
 * @param {String} att The style property to set. 
 * @param {String|Number} val The value. 
 */
setStyle: function(node, att, val, style) {
    style = style || node.style;
    var CUSTOM_STYLES = Y_DOM.CUSTOM_STYLES;

    if (style) {
        if (val === null || val === '') { // normalize unsetting
            val = '';
        } else if (!isNaN(new Number(val)) && re_unit.test(att)) { // number values may need a unit
            val += Y_DOM.DEFAULT_UNIT;
        }

        if (att in CUSTOM_STYLES) {
            if (CUSTOM_STYLES[att].set) {
                CUSTOM_STYLES[att].set(node, val, style);
                return; // NOTE: return
            } else if (typeof CUSTOM_STYLES[att] === 'string') {
                att = CUSTOM_STYLES[att];
            }
        } else if (att === '') { // unset inline styles
            att = 'cssText';
            val = '';
        }
        style[att] = val; 
    }
},
```

Anybody have any idea what's happening here ? im using a datatable and Alloy UI to implement the table, also im noticing that the dom manipulation for the table is not working just for IE8, this is the code :

```
var nodeObject = Y.one('#myDataTable table');
nodeObject.removeClass('table-table');
nodeObject.addClass('table');
nodeObject.addClass('mytable');
nodeObject.addClass('table-hover');
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your issued, but: `if (val === null || val === '') { val = '';}`. Why the `||`? If *val* is `''`, why assign `''`? Got me beat. Oh, It might help if you show the call too.

Comment: Hey @RobG that's the yui module tho i can't change that and to be honest i don't think thats the problem. Im using liferay so trying to find the call that triggers that module is really hard.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not the issue, just weird code. Also `!isNaN(new Number(val))` seems like a very expensive way to do `!isNaN(+val)` (BTW, both return *true* for an empty Array and "" (empty string)) so it's very difficult to determine exactly what the code is trying to do.

Comment: Nobody can throw some light here ? i have been dealing with this issue for weeks now and it seems like there's not feedback at all here or on the yui sites.

Comment: Where exactly is `Line: 18772`? IE's errors are a bit cryptic, the line number may be the actual line with the error or the one before. What values are being passed to *node*, *att*, *val* and *style*?

Comment: @RobG This is the line: style[att] = val;, and this is how the values are passed :
`Y.all('.pagination-content li:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-last-of-ype(n+2)').addClass('ocultar');
ocultar = Y.all('.ocultar');
ocultar.setStyle('display','none');`
As you can see the third line shows how the setStyle is called.

Comment: @Lowtrux Where did this code come from: `setStyle: function(node, att, val, style)`

Comment: @PaulSweatte from the Alloy UI core files (YUI3), the file is called dom-style.js. That's why is so hard for me to understand where's the problem since is not my code is the YUI core code and apparently it works just fine on IE8. As i said before is like just IE8 is not recognizing any of my yui code, but at the same time is rendering the DataTable.

Comment: `IE8 is not recognizing any of my yui code`. Compare it to the [sample code](http://alloyui.com/examples/datatable/real-world/)

Answer (score 0):

The following selector is invalid:

```
:nth-last-of-ype(n+2)
```

It should be:

```
:nth-last-of-type(n+2)
```

The `setStyle` method takes a DOM node as its first argument:

- @param {HTMLElement} An HTMLElement to apply the style to.
- @param {String} att The style property to set.
- @param {String|Number} val The value.

So, this syntax:

```
ocultar.setStyle('display','none');
```

Has an invalid argument, since `display` is not a DOM node.

**References**

- [YUI: setStyle method](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DOM.html#method_setStyle)
- [Differences between YUI 2.x and YUI3 setStyle](https://miketaylr.com/posts/2014/01/yui-set-style-differences.html)

Comment: Yeah that was a typo when copying the code to the previous comment, that's not the problem. Also i guess you are not right regarding the setStyle argument. From the YUI Library:

`setStyle ( attr  val ) chainable
Provided by the node-style module.
Defined in node/js/node-style.js:78
Sets a style property on each node. Use camelCase (e.g. 'backgroundColor') for multi-word properties.
Parameters:

attr String
The style attribute to set.

val String | Number
The value.`

Everything is working fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE9, IE10, IE11 but not for IE8.

Comment: @Lowtrux nth-of-type is [not supported in IE8](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t57) as well...

Comment: yeah i know but ie8 is not even showing the whole widget. When i explore the elements on IE8 the HTML structure created by YUI (and showing and working fine in other browsers) is not even there.